# how to read the x,y position of xcode UITextView created in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uitextview

How can I read the x,y position and width of a `UITextView` created in storyboard?

At run-time, I need to programatically create other objects immediately below the UITextBox?
And all run-time created objects must be based on the position of the storyboard `UITextView`.

I could find no answer to this.  And the code that I tried (below) returns 0,0

in .h...

```
@interface ataglance_central_controller : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextView *transmitter_box;
}
```

in .m....................

```
enter code here
#import "ataglance_central_controller.h"
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h> 
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>


#import "TransferService.h"

@interface ataglance_central_controller () <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate>
{
UITextView* battery_status_textview;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView   *textview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBCentralManager      *centralManager;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CBPeripheral          *discoveredPeripheral;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData         *data;

@end



@implementation ataglance_central_controller

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
        NSLog(@"    ataglance_central_controller.m viewDidLoad.     ");
   [super viewDidLoad];


NSLog(@" x <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< b  %f",  transmitter_box.frame.origin.x );
NSLog(@" y <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< b  %f", transmitter_box.frame.origin.y );

}


-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

NSLog(@" x viewDidLayoutSubviews  %f", transmitter_box.frame.origin.x );

NSLog(@" y viewDidLayoutSubviews  %f", transmitter_box.frame.origin.y );


}
```

log

```
2013-05-21 12:12:10.708 DW x2[447:c07]  ataglance_central_controller.m viewDidLoad.     
2013-05-21 12:12:10.709 DW x2[447:c07]  x <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< b  0.000000
2013-05-21 12:12:10.709 DW x2[447:c07]  y <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< b  0.000000
2013-05-21 12:12:10.712 DW x2[447:c07] Battery status is unknown.
2013-05-21 12:12:10.743 DW x2[447:c07]  x viewDidLayoutSubviews  270.000000
2013-05-21 12:12:10.744 DW x2[447:c07]  y viewDidLayoutSubviews  12.000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging the frame details in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`. If your 
Storyboard is setup to use AutoLayout subviews get positioned later than you might think...

Of course this shouldn't stop you from adding other subviews in viewDidLoad and positioning them relative to the UITextView using auto layout constraints rather than setting their frames directly.

Comment: Done.  Now y is correct but x=270 is wrong. ipad storyboard (landscape) transmitter_box UITextView is actually 14,12 (width=990 height=143)

Comment: I corrected the x=270 problem by moving the declarations from .m to .h where they should go in the first place. (I got the original code from Apple Dev's BTLE central/peripheral transfer, which had the @interface in both the .h and .m files, which beyond my level of clairvoyance.)

Comment: Cool. I would still recommend using `NSLayoutConstraint`s to specify the positions of your programatically created UIViews relative to the UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

The layer sits inside your `UITextView` and fills its owner.

What you're looking for is the `frame` of your control: `transmitter_box.frame.origin.x`, `transmitter_box.frame.origin.y`.

Comment: I did that, but it still returns 0,0.  (Code updated above)
Also, it's a TextView not a textfield, if that matters.

Comment: Really? A minus? What for? @DouglasK.Bell you should also check that your `textView` is initialized, it might not be if it wasn't linked correctly from the storyboard.

Comment: I think someone minus'd it because it had 'textfield' instead of 'UITextView'.  But I think a comment would have been more polite and respectful.

Comment: @DouglasK.Bell thanks for the hint. Yes, it's pretty awful and nonconstructive when someone gives a minus without leaving the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your answer, fortunately you have already found it. You do however seem to be deviating from the Objective-C naming conventions.

```
@interface ataglance_central_controller
```

should be something more like

```
@interface MYAtAGlanceCentralController
```

class names should start with capital letters, (and be prefixed with something)

Comment: Agreed.  I was in a hurry (tight development schedule). However, I like to insert a space (underscore) between words for readability, so that I don't deviate from English syntactical conventions -- English being a somewhat debugged system of communication.  ;-)